# Mass virtual hosting: map any portnumber to own domain name

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

I need to define rule (using `mod_rewrite` i think) to map any port to `portnumber.domain.com`. How to do that in Apache2 ? Now i have one config for each port number like below.

```
# 9003.domain.com
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 9003.domain.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9003/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9003/
</VirtualHost>

# 9004.domain.com
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 9004.domain.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9004/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9004/
</VirtualHost>

# and so on....
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do something with [ProxyPassMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassmatch), maybe something like

`ProxyPassMatch ^([0-9{2,5}]) http://127.0.0.1:$1`

Comment: I don't think this will work. ProxyPassMatch operates against the URL, not the HOST name.

Comment: He's looking to match the port in the URL.. my example is just theory though :)

Comment: He's trying to match 9003.domain.com and proxy it to localhost:9003. Since ProxyPassMatch only tries to match against the path part of the URL, not the Hostname part you can't use it here.

Comment: I think I see what you mean, but I can't find anything that says that it matches against the path only.. I ask seriously, can you link me to the documentation so I can inform myself?

Comment: I have the impression that the documentation is not very clear here:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassmatch
The description of ProxyPass makes it clear that it is path, not url that is matched. The description of ProxaPassMatch seems to imply that it is URLs that are matched, but the examples given tell a different story.

Comment: Yeah, I've looked through it pretty thoroughly, and cross referenced every term they used in the glossary, they say url, and in the apache httpd glossary url is the entire address including http:// the FQDN and the path. Which is why I was hoping you had something I missed.. maybe we (or me) should ask them to update the documentation.

Comment: I tested it, and ProxaPassMatch appears not to match against the hostname part of the URL

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8843/discussion-between-nickw-and-krist-van-besien)

Answer (score 1):

I did some corrections on @Krist answer and make it works now. `403 error` was from `RewriteEngine On` absence.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     RewriteEngine On
     ServerAlias *.domain.com
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}      (\d+).domain.com
     RewriteRule ^/(.*)$           http://localhost:%1/$1    [P]
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

A RewriteRule would indeed do it.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

Servername www.domain.com
ServerAlias *.domain.com

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}      (\d+).domain.com
RewriteRule (.*)              http://localhost:%1/$1    [P]

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks for You response, but i've got `403: Forbidden Error`. Do You know what can i do ?

Comment: Have a look in the error log of your webserver. A 403 means that the server won't give you the content for some reason, and the reason is usually mentioned in the log.